# When I run python file in Visual Studio 2022 Community, it will open the Python file in a new terminal window

Tags: python, visual-studio, terminal, visual-studio-2022

When I run python file in Visual Studio 2022 community, it will open the Python file in a new terminal window. How do I open it inside Visual Studio 2022 community, not in new terminal window?

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yS7R.png)

Is it Visual Studio 2022 Community problem or my PC?

Comment: Looks like you are not using vscode. It seems to be Visual Studio.

Comment: Right.  It's not a Visual Studio problem nor is it a PC problem.  That's just the way Visual Studio handles Python files.  If you want an embedded terminal, try VSCode instead.